# Scala Option Impact

Tags: scala, chisel

I am having trouble with the scala `.getorElse` command. I want to generate `AVec` at all times, but I only want `AVec` and `BVec` when `elemA >= 50`, and lastly, I want all of them to be generated when `elemA >= 100`. I have tried `.get` with no luck and below you can see the implementation with `.getorElse`.

Any advice on how to implement this correctly would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
 val AVec = Reg(Vec(10, Valid(Vec(10, UInt(8.W)))))

 val BVec = if(elemA >= 50){
   Some(Reg(Vec(11, Valid(Vec(11, UInt(8.W))))))
 } else {
   None
 }

 val CVec = if(elemA >= 100){
   Some(Reg(Vec(12, Valid(Vec(12, UInt(8.W))))))
 } else {
   None
 }


 when(io.elemB.fire()){
   when(io.elemC === 0.U){
     AVec.map{_.valid := false.B}
   }.elsewhen(io.elemC === 1.U){
     AVec.map{_.valid := false.B}
     BVec.getOrElse(AVec).map{_.valid := false.B}
   }.otherwise{
     AVec.map{_.valid := false.B}
     BVec.getOrElse(AVec).map{_.valid := false.B}
     CVec.getOrElse(CVec).map{_.valid := false.B} //<------Issues coming here
   }
 }
```

Comment: You are using `getOrElse` wrong. It is used to provide an alternate value, to be used for cases where the `Option` is `None`. You are providing `CVec` to be used as alternate value when `CVec` is None. This does not make any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the style of what you're writing, why not do?

```scala
CVec.getOrElse(AVec).map{_.valid := false.B}
```

That being said, there are more idomatic ways use `Option`. I'd suggest checking out some tutorials on `Option` in Scala, eg. https://www.baeldung.com/scala/option-type

In particular, you don't always need to "get" the `Option`. Think about an `Option` as a `List` or `Array` with exactly zero or one elements. Just like you can `map` or `foreach` a `List` (or chisel3 `Vec` as you're doing here), you can `map` or `foreach` an `Option`. Consider the following:

```scala
 when(io.elemB.fire()){
   when(io.elemC === 0.U){
     // Note that I used () instead of {}, this is a stylistic choice
     // Generally you use {} only when there are multiple Statements in the anonymous function
     // If this doesn't make sense to you yet, just ignore it, it's fine to use {} :)
     AVec.map(_.valid := false.B)
   }.elsewhen(io.elemC === 1.U){
     AVec.map(_.valid := false.B)
     BVec.foreach(_.map(_.valid := false.B))
   }.otherwise{
     AVec.map(_.valid := false.B)
     BVec.foreach(_.map(_.valid := false.B))
     CVec.foreach(_.map(_.valid := false.B))
   }
```

Just like `AVec.map(f)` applies `f` to each element of the `Vec`, `BVec.foreach(g)` applies `g` to the contents of `BVec` if it is `Some`, or does nothing otherwise. This is 2 levels of function nesting deep which may look a bit alien when you're new to Chisel/Scala, but is a common way to express this.

Alternatively, you could test the options and use `.get`, this is often more familiar to people new to functional programming (ie. most people new to Chisel):

```scala
 when(io.elemB.fire()){
   when(io.elemC === 0.U){
     AVec.map(_.valid := false.B)
   }.elsewhen(io.elemC === 1.U){
     AVec.map(_.valid := false.B)
     if (BVec.isDefined) {
       BVec.get.map(_.valid := false.B)
     }
   }.otherwise{
     AVec.map(_.valid := false.B)
     if (BVec.isDefined) {
       BVec.get.map(_.valid := false.B)
     }
     if (CVec.isDefined) {
       CVec.get.map(_.valid := false.B)
     }
   }
```

If this looks a little more verbose (you have to write `CVec` twice), that's what `foreach` is for. This "if defined, do `.get` and do something" is literally the [implementation](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/60b503bcfdd61e086fa6b978c38009f2604dd365/src/library/scala/Option.scala#L406) of `Option.foreach`.